# Delphi 5 Form Caption Font Size

Tags: delphi, font-size, delphi-5

I am currently resizing my Delphi5 application from 800x600 to be scalable up to 1440x1080.

The only thing that still looks too small is the Form Caption and the ShowMessage/MessageDlg text.

Am I right in thinking the ShowMessage text is related to the Windows default size?

Is there any way to increase the Form Caption font size? It doesn't seem connected to the Form font size.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font size of the title bar is handled by windows and is system wide. If you want modify the font or other attibutes you must draw manually the non client area of the form(Windows).

Until Windows XP  you can draw directly in the caption(title) bar modifying the font , color and text handling the [`WM_NCPAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, starting with windows vista and the [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) introduction you must use the [DwmSetWindowAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the [`DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value in order to use this technique.